# E4 RCP How to set Toolbar item from preferences on start-up

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

Eclipse E4 (4.4.2), I have a *Handled Tool Item* defined in the Application model at,
 Windows and Dialogs -> TrimBars -> Window Trim -> Toolbar

The *Type* of the item is *Check*. An option of the item call *Selected*, assigns the default selection of the Toolbar item when the RCP application is launched. I am persisting the current state of the tool bar item in *org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.InstanceScope* (other non-UI preferences as also stored here).

Is there a way to set the selection state of the tool bar item when the application is re-launched to the value stored in my preferences? i.e. if tool bar item is selected on exiting the application it is selected on launching, if tool bar item is de-selected on existing the application it is not selected on launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way since the Eclipse Application Platform doesn't know anything about the preferences.

You could use a model processor defined using the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` extension point to add code to initialize the item.

```xml
<extension
     id="themeContribution"
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  <processor
        beforefragment="false"
        class="package.ItemProcessor">
     <element
           id="item.id">
     </element>
  </processor>
```

Alternatively you should be able to write code to set the tool bar item value from the preferences in the `@ProcessAdditions` method of your application LifeCycle class (assuming you have one). Note the `@PostContextCreate` method is probably called to early for this.